Error initializing Shopify Hydrogen project: ENOENT no such file or directory
I am trying to initialize a new Shopify Hydrogen project using the Shopify CLI on my Windows machine by referring shopify's document . However, I keep encountering an error related to file paths that. Here's what
Screenshot of Error:
Node version: v18.12.0
npm version : 8.19.2
Question:
How can I resolve this ENOENT error when initializing a Shopify Hydrogen project on Windows? Is there a specific workaround for handling this issue, or any other steps I might be missing?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I tried to run this command : npm create @shopify/hydrogen@latest -- --quickstart
expected :
Shopify:   Mock.shop
Language:  JavaScript
Routes:
• Home (/ & /:catchAll)
• Page (/pages/:handle)
• Cart (/cart/* & /discount/)
• Products (/products/:handle)
• Collections (/collections & /collections/:handle)
• Policies (/policies & /policies/:handle)
• Blogs (/blogs/)
• Account (/account/*)
• Search (/api/predictive-search & /search)
• Robots (/robots.txt)
• Sitemap (/sitemap.xml)
